# Изменился интерфейс мобильной версии сайта

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия, интерфейс

Вчера интерфейс stackoverflow выглядил так:
[image]

Зайдя сегодня интерфейс стал таким:

[image]

Это произошло только в русском stackoverflow.

Почему он стал таким и как его исправить?

Comment: Внизу страницы кликните "мобильная версия". Иногда состояние сбрасывается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Иногда выбранное ранее состояние отображения сайта (мобильная, полноразмерная версии) сбрасывается и включается некая «предпочтительная». В таком случае надо самостоятельно еще раз включить желаемую версию отображения сайта в подвале страницы: мобильная версия, полная версия.

До очередного следующего сброса сайт будет отображаться в выбранном пользователем режиме.